# Add extra space on li-style-element

Tags: html, css, html-lists

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>eins</li>
    <li>zwei</li>
    <li>drei</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li::before {
  content: "– " " ";
}
li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  text-indent: -10px;
}
```

I would like to add an extra space after the `-` of each `li`. I tried:

```
content: "-&nbsp;"
```

but it doesnt work. How can I add this.

thanks
thomas

Answer (score 1):

You can moderate the space by adding `padding-right` to it.

Like this

```css
li::before {
  content: "+";
  padding-right: 10px;
}
li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  text-indent: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>eins</li>
    <li>zwei</li>
    <li>drei</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `\00a0` (unicode) in css `content`

`content: "–\00a0\00a0\";`

try: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh6ro16g/

Answer (score 0):

Place `:before` with `position: absolute` and increase / decrease `padding-left` on `<li>` to set indent as much as you want. This method will allow you to have text aligned vertically even if it goes in multiple lines.

```css
li::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "–";
  top: 1px;
  left: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>eins</li>
    <li>zwei</li>
    <li>drei</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can increase / decrease space using padding-right on li as much as you want.

```
<ul>
<li>eins</li>
<li>zwei</li>
<li>drei</li>
enter</ul>

li:before {
    content: "-";
    padding-right: 20px;
}
li{
    list-style:outside none;

    }
```